# Collecting of the answers going to the database

Tags: php, database

[Ccan someone give me an idea how to collect the Answers coming from the radio button going to the database? BTW im using PHP as my backend language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37JyB.png)

Comment: The question is very wide. You are probably not asking for an answer explaining how you set up a PHP script, send form data (?) from the client process it in the back end, set up a database and write to it from PHP. So what is your particular problem?

Comment: My problem is my project is faculty evaluation, the student will evaluate the teacher. Each question has a 5 designated radio button for scoring. So my problem is i need to collect all the score going from my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to help you. If I got your question right you have a form, which has a radio button and you need to confirm which option has been selected to save it in your database. Is that correct? Well If that the case you could do something like this.

Lets say you have a radio button that looks something like this:

```
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
```

When your form has been posted you can get the value like this:

```
if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

And them just create a query to your DB.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Yes i need to collect the answers from the radio button then send it to the database, did you saw the picture attached?

Comment: My project is all about faculty evaluation, each question has 5 designated radio button for scoring

Comment: ok, so the form will be similar to the one I show you before but will have 5 input with the value going from 0 to 5. Them you can check the returned value the same way,  getting the $_POST['name_of_radio'] . Them it will depend on your Database how you will generate the query. It will be helpful to know which part of the process you are having problems with. is the form part or getting the parameters with php ? or saving the data into you database?

Comment: I think both, im only a beginner in programming but im so thirsty to learn. My goal for now  is to collect the answers going to database and next is to generate a report coming from the collected answers in the database.

Comment: I am happy to hear you are thirsty to learn. I will recommend your to read a bit more about the subject and this may help you make more concrete questions. I can highly recommend you this site http://www.w3schools.com there you can find tutoriasl on how to create forms, how to process those form using PHP and them how to save them to you Database. Well the last part depends on the type of Database you want to use. Good Luck.

Comment: Yes im struggling right now but im so eager to finish this thesis project. I created the lay out from scratch. Now my problem is the backend development. Yes you're right i need to add more to my foundation so i can totally learn the process and flow. Thanks buddy!